# I have a problem to load a bmp image on sdl2

Tags: c, load, sdl, sdl-2, bmp

I feel like I have a problem uploading my image
tmp is equal to null

> tmp    0x00000000    SDL_Surface *
> *the problem may come from my path to load the bmp, that's why I put the entire path*

#include "main.h"

```
int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;
    SDL_Texture* image = NULL;
    int statut = EXIT_FAILURE;
    SDL_Color blanc = { 255, 255, 255, 255 };
    if (0 != init(&window, &renderer, 640, 480)) /* *ecrire cette fonction */
        goto Quit;

   image = loadImage("C:\\workspace\\projet\\MadocWord\\back.bmp", renderer); /* ecrire cette fonction*/
    if (NULL == image)
        goto Quit;

    statut = EXIT_SUCCESS;
   setWindowColor(renderer, blanc); /* *ecrire cette fonction* */
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    SDL_Delay(3000);

Quit:
    if (NULL != image)
        SDL_DestroyTexture(image);
    if (NULL != renderer)
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    if (NULL != window)
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return statut;
}
SDL_Texture* loadImage(const char path[], SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    SDL_Surface* tmp = NULL;
    SDL_Texture* texture = NULL;
    tmp = SDL_LoadBMP(path);
    if (NULL == tmp)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur SDL_LoadBMP : %s", SDL_GetError());
        return NULL;
    }
    texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, tmp);
    SDL_FreeSurface(tmp);
    if (NULL == texture)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface : %s", SDL_GetError());
        return NULL;
    }
    return texture;
}
```

but this didn't work either. Same error. Have I written something wrong, or missed some part?

Comment: What does `SDL_GetError()` says when `SDL_LoadBMP` fails?

Comment: <Error reading characters from the string.> @Martin

Answer (score 0):

Couple of observations.

- project is spelled wrong.  Is that intentional?
  image = loadImage("C:\workspace\projet\MadocWord\back.bmp", renderer);
- I know the escape backslashes are necessary for output in C, is it for SDL_LoadBMP? and does the array path carry it properly to LoadBMP?
- if you are using workspace, it sounds like you are using Eclipse.  The later versions use eclipse-workspace. Are you confident in the path to the picture.

Just thinking out loud.